# Can't create postgis extension on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've got a Postgres database and user I've created on Google Cloud SQL.

I'm trying to install the postgis extension for that user:

```
myuser=> CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "postgis"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

as you can see, it won't allow me to create the extension for this user, so I attempted to make this user a superuser from the `postgres` role:

```
postgres=> ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER;
ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superusers
```

and I get the following error. This is because Google Cloud SQL does not allow the `SUPERUSER` role for any postgres accounts according to: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users.

So I'm in this weird state of purgatory that I need to add this extension, but can't.

Any tips on how to proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like creating a new user through the API (or the console) will give it the proper permissions, at least according to the prompt when trying to add additional users through the console:

[image]

Comment: The link on the screenshot points to here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users

Comment: Wow! Thank you!!

Comment: I am having a similar problem, but creating a new user did not seem to solve the issue (although I do get the same message)